# Running Application in Specific Network Namespace Without Sudo?

Tags: sudo, network-namespaces

I am trying to run google-chrome with a specific network namespace, but when I do there is no audio. I run the command so that it is running in the network namespace as follows:

```
sudo ip netns exec myns sudo -u "$USER" google-chrome
```

The specific problem here seem to be that I have to use sudo. I use `sudo -u` here to run it under my specific user, but it isn't able to play audio and doesn't show up in the system audio mixer list of processes. It is run under my user though.

Similarly I get the same problem if I don't use the network namespace, just running the sudo command will stop audio from playing.

```
sudo -u "$USER" google-chrome
```

So I could put it in the network namespace I want without using sudo should solve the problem. Or maybe someone else knows another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

To pass through your local environment variables, run `sudo` with `-E`.